# Is there a way to tell if python was configured and compiled with "--with-threads --enable-shared"?

Tags: python, debian

This is for Python 2.6.6 on Debian Squeeez. I'm trying to find out if the binaries shipped with debian were configured with the flags of:

```
--with-threads --enable-shared
```

as if they were not I will need to compile and install from source myself.

Comment: Try parsing info from pyconfig.h? This file is generated during the compile time and is platform specific. Not sure if it has all the flags, though :( Also running python -v might reveal some information.

Comment: if you guys using newest version of python check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201498/how-to-check-if-python3-was-built-with-enable-shared and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192758/how-to-get-the-list-of-options-that-python-was-compiled-with

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`--with-threads` (which is the default) will mean Python supports threading, which will mean `import thread` will work. An easy way to test this is with `python$version -m threading`

`--enable-shared` will mean Python comes with a `libpython$version.so` file, installed in `$prefix/lib` (alongside the `python$version` directory, not inside it.) The easiest thing to do is to look if that file is there -- assuming you want to know because you need to use this libpython shared library. If you actually need to know if the `python$version` *binary* uses this shared library, `ldd` will tell you that. I make that distinction because on Debian, `/usr/lib/python$version.so` will exist even though `/usr/bin/python$version` is statically linked.

Comment: And by `import thread` works, you mean it won't throw an `ImportError`, which you can test for in from Python code.