# How do I find the build configuration for the windows 2.7.6 download from Python.org

Tags: python-2.7

As a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23295092/3524756), I have tried to find the build configuration for the 2.7.6 windows binary download from python.org. I can't see anything on the download site and the sysconfig module doesn't have a "CONFIG_ARGS" entry in _CONFIG_VARS, so I can't find it from that either. Thank again.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192758/how-to-get-the-list-of-options-that-python-was-compiled-with