# whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-wheel

I am new to python, and am trying to install some modules/packages using .whl file.  The system does not have access to the internet so everything is local.

- I'm running RHEL 6.9 64bit 2.6.32-696.10.1.el6.x86_64
- Python is version 2.7.12 (altinstalled with 2.6)
- platform.architecture()
  ('64bit', 'ELF')
- I'm running pip 9.0.1

Attempt at installing numpy:

```
# /usr/local/bin/pip2.7 install numpy-1.13.3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
numpy-1.13.3-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Do you know which `--enable-unicode` argument was used at Python interpreter build time?

Comment: (Alternately, are you willing to consider using a Docker image for your Python runtime from the `manylinux` folks? That'll give you something *guaranteed* compatible).

Comment: You might consider starting from the [Platform Detection for Installers](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux/blob/master/pep-513.rst#platform-detection-for-installers) section of PEP-513 -- walking through the code there should give you an idea of where things fail.

Comment: I used --enable-unicode=ucs4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192758

Answer (score 3):

`cp27-cp27m` manylinux packages are compatible with a Python interpreter compiled with `--enable-unicode=ucs2`.

For an interpreter compiled with `--enable-unicode=ucs4`, you instead need `cp27-cp27mu` packages.