# What does the 'm' in a Python ABI tag mean?

Tags: python, abi

PEP 425 explains the compatibility tag format for built python distributions, but does not explain the ABI tag in full detail.

The ABI tag can end with a combination of the letters 'd', 'm', and 'u'. As an example, it is explained within the PEP that the 'd' means an ABI with debugging, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839079/318877) explains that the 'u' denotes an interpreter compiled with `--enable-unicode=ucs4`, but I could not find the meaning of the 'm' anywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per [PEP 3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/), `m` indicates that the ABI in question is using [the `pymalloc` allocator](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#pymalloc):

> Python implementations MAY include additional flags in the file name tag as appropriate. For example, on POSIX systems these flags will also contribute to the file name:
>
> - `--with-pydebug` (flag: `d`)
> - `--with-pymalloc` (flag: `m`)
> - `--with-wide-unicode` (flag: `u`)

Comment: It is worth noting that Python 3.8 eliminates the `m` flag.

Comment: @rdb: Similarly, as of 3.3 (which implemented [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/)), "wide unicode" isn't a thing (they went from a hardcoded two or four bytes per character, determined when Python was built, to a flexible representation that uses 1, 2 or 4 bytes per character, depending on the max ordinal, so any system can represent any Unicode character, without always using four bytes per character).