# Python slower inside docker container

Tags: python, docker, performance

I'm experiencing a slower python when running from inside of a docker container than the one of my system. I can't explain this difference.

I've found a lot of content about this on the Internet, but the solutions I've tried don't work.

#### Test

Host system Up-to-date *Arch linux*

```
$ python --version
Python 3.11.5

$ python -m timeit 'from random import randrange
for _ in range(100): [randrange(50,500) for _ in range(randrange(30000,50000))]'

1 loop, best of 5: 3.07 sec per loop
```

Using python:3.11.5 docker image

```
$ docker run python:3.11.5-slim python --version
Python 3.11.5

$ docker run python:3.11.5-slim python -m timeit 'from random import randrange
for _ in range(100): [randrange(50,500) for _ in range(randrange(30000,50000))]'

1 loop, best of 5: 3.99 sec per loop
```

I've tried many times with more loops, and the result is the same. 0.5 to 1 sec more time when run inside container.

I've tried with `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined` but it does not make a major difference

What is happening on my system ? docker isn't supposed to add such overhead.

#### Edit: other tests

##### Bash loop

On local system:

```
$ bash -c "time for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j<$(shuf -i 7000-8000 -n 1); j++)); do
        :
    done
done"
```

Empiric (manually run 10 times in a row) result around 2.1s

Inside docker container

```
$ docker run python:3.11.5-slim bash -c "time for ((i=0; i<100; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j<$(shuf -i 7000-8000 -n 1); j++)); do
        :
    done
done"
```

Empiric (manually run 10 times in a row) result around 2.5s

##### Python complex math

On local system:

```
$ python -m timeit '(82637**533333).bit_length()'
1 loop, best of 5: 1.36 sec per loop
```

Inside docker container

```
$ docker run python:3.11.5-slim python -m timeit '(82637**533333).bit_length()'
1 loop, best of 5: 1.63 sec per loop
```

Comment: It's possible that the Python in that Docker image is compiled with a less optimizing compiler, or with different compiler flags, for instance.

Comment: @AKX would disassembling using [dis package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) help to analyse the problem?

Comment: @dankal444 No, since it would only get you Python bytecode, and it will be the same between two Python versions.

Comment: Also mind that, when your host python is not constrained in RAM and CPU usage, your container could well be, by your docker daemon settings.

Comment: Maybe try with another command too, say `time dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=100M count=20` to see how fast both environments generate 2 gigs of randomness?

Comment: Please check if: 1. the startup time is negligible or not; 2. same for the import time; 3. this is also slow or not with list operations and not just random-based functions (you can also test the speed of pure math operations with `print((82637**1261597).bit_length())`).

Comment: I've added two tests. 1. python complex math 2. bash dumb loop. Both are still slower inside docker container

Comment: Regarding the compilation flags, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192758/how-to-get-the-list-of-options-that-python-was-compiled-with) can help a bit, but on some machines (like mine), there is no useful infos. To be sure that the problem comes from the build, you need to build CPython on both environment. You can also use a packaged embedded version (same binaries on both env). The best solution is to use tools like Nix so to be 100% sure that the environment is the same. With that you can find if the problem is docker or the environment.

Comment: Note that with the compilation of CPython alone, libraries like the libc might be different and some versions are faster than others. The compiler needs to be the same and at the same version too. Doing this manually is cumbersome and error-prone. This is why I recommended Nix.