# testing python for threading

Tags: python, macos

How do you test if the version of python that comes pre-installed on your machine (in this case, Mac Lion) was compiled with support for threading?

Here's my info:

```
[16:31 7] uname -a
Darwin leopard.local 11.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.3.0: Thu Jan 12 18:47:41 PST 2012; root:xnu-1699.24.23~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386
[16:31 8] which python
/usr/bin/python
[16:31 9] python --version
Python 2.7.1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "support for threading"?  How about entering "import threading" at a python command line?

Comment: I was reading the document for installing mod_wsgi and its python requirement was (quote): "The version of Python being used must have been compiled with support for threading."

Comment: Here's the document I was talking about above: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickInstallationGuide

Comment: if "import threading" works you have support for threading. Also, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193773/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-python-was-configured-and-compiled-with-with-thread

Comment: Thank you, TJD and pycoder112358. Please let me give you credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments by [TJD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914466/tjd) and [pycoder112358](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1150563/pycoder112358), you can test if your Python installation has support for threading by running:

```
import threading
```

at the Python command line. If the `threading` module is not installed, this command will raise an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import threading
ImportError: No module named threading
```

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139075/187647) for why I'm answering an old post.