# Tell if python allows threading from within a python script

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there any way for a python script to detect whether or not it is allowed to use threading?  I'm currently writing a wiki engine, and I would like for it to be able to take advantage of threading.  However, not all hosting environments allow python scripts to use threading (for example, free accounts at PythonAnywhere), so I would like for the script to be able to detect this and disable threaded mode on such environments.

**NOTE:** I have already checked the question below, and it is not a duplicate of my question, as it addresses a different topic:
[Is there a way to tell if python was configured and compiled with "--with-threads --enable-shared"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193773/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-python-was-configured-and-compiled-with-with-thread)

Comment: And `import thread` is not covered at all in the other link that I indicated.

Comment: It is in the answer. I am testing this on PythonAnywhere right now; unfortunately, the import works there. Are you sure threading is disallowed?

Comment: Threading is allowed, provided that you have a paid account.

Comment: I see no evidence of that in the help or marketing materials. I only see CPU limits.

Comment: Then I may be confused.  However, I do know that they impose a limit on WSGI worker threads.

Comment: That is something entirely different. That just means they configured the WSGI server that serves your web app with a limit based on your price tier.

Comment: Okay, based on a forum post, it appears that they do block threads for free accounts, and initially allowed them only for web developer accounts: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/432/

Comment: I can start a bash shell or a Python session, do `import thread` and use `thread.start_new_thread(lambda: None, ())` to start new threads just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a try statement at the beginning of your script that asserts a piece of code that requires multithreading. If it fails, make a change in the except block to a logical indicator for whether or not the script should use multithreading.