# How to check if Python3 was built with '--enable-shared'?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, homebrew

**Environment:**

- Mac OS X 10.8.5
- Apache 2.2.26
- Homebrew Python 3.3.3

**Problem:**

I am trying to install mod_wsgi but first need to determine if Python was configured and compiled with the '--enable-shared' option.

**Questions:**

1. How can I determine if Homebrew installed Python with the '--enable-shared' option?
2. If it was not installed, what is the correct way to install it?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192758/how-to-get-a-list-of-options-that-python-was-compiled-with - This works with python 3.

Comment: The ``--enable-shared`` option will not be relevant if Python was installed as a MacOS X style framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the python repl:

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_config_vars('Py_ENABLE_SHARED')
```

Comment: thanks! 'print(sysconfig.get_config_vars('Py_ENABLE_SHARED'))' returned 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' but just 'sysconfig.get_config_vars('Py_ENABLE_SHARED')' returned '[0]', which I'm assuming means false / "this feature is not enabled".

Comment: Correct, it is a boolean return so, you are correct. The feature is not enabled.  I will fix the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

A bit better is to use

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_ENABLE_SHARED')
```

This returns the integer value 0 or 1 directly.
The plural form is used to get multiple values or a whole dict if no argument is given, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html?highlight=get_config_vars#sysconfig.get_config_vars